# Tftp transfer timeout on fedora in virtual box

Tags: tftp

I am able to to do tftp on my machine as local host and can get the file.

But when i am trying to do the same from other machine connected to same switch and are in same netwrok. I am getting Transfer timed out.

```
[root@Nagra rchakena]# tftp 10.12.129.75
tftp> get test
Transfer timed out.


tftp> status
Connected to 10.12.129.75.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off Literal: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
```

Can please some help how to get fix done for this?

Comment: i have the same issue except the server is Ubuntu and client is fedora. Both can ping each other and are on a 172.x private network. Still tftp fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with TFTP client under VMware because of NAT network on my virtual machine. When I switched to bridged connection it worked: was able to get files, get ip address via DHCP and boot via PXE.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, TFTP opens port 69 but the transfer itself also opens an additional random port (like FTP does) when that port gets filtered by a firewall the transfer will systematically timeout.